# Oracle GROUP BY doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I got SQL query like this:

```
SELECT Z.ID,
       Z.ZADAVATEL,
       Z.DATUM_ZADANI,
       Z.LIN_OBL,
       Z.DRUH_ZMENY,
       Z.CISLO_ZMENY,
       Z.PRILOHY
FROM   ZMENY Z
       JOIN ZMENY_DILY ZD
       ON (ZD.ID_ZMENY=Z.ID)
WHERE  1=1 %sql
ORDER BY Z.ID DESC %lmt%ofs
```

Table ZMENY has 9 rows, ZMENY_DILY has 11 rows. The problem is I get 11 rows as a result but 2 of them are duplicate rows and I'm trying to get rid off these two duplicates, I tried to use

```
GROUP BY Z.ID
```

unfortunately Oracle says: **ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression**

I'm not much into Oracle, MySQL wouldn't have any problem I guess ... any tips ?

Comment: First, you should identify what those two extra rows represent. Assuming that each entry of `ZMENY` has a matching row in `ZMENY_DILY` and two entries has an extra row -- what do those extra rows mean? Answer that question and I'm sure the answer to your question will jump right out at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need group by in this case you can use select distinct

```
SELECT distinct  
    Z.ID, 
    Z.ZADAVATEL, 
    Z.DATUM_ZADANI,
    Z.LIN_OBL,
    Z.DRUH_ZMENY,
    Z.CISLO_ZMENY,
    Z.PRILOHY 
FROM ZMENY Z JOIN ZMENY_DILY ZD ON (ZD.ID_ZMENY=Z.ID)
ORDER BY Z.ID DESC %lmt%ofs
```

Comment: Using DISTINCT threw this error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Comment: You can't put a CLOB in the WHERE clause.  Be sure you have not a cblog in where .

Comment: yeah, the problem was in SELECT ... I had to use function to_char on CLOB columns :) thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select distinct`, assuming all columns are duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Z.ID, Z.ZADAVATEL, Z.DATUM_ZADANI, Z.LIN_OBL,
       Z.DRUH_ZMENY, Z.CISLO_ZMENY, Z.PRILOHY
FROM ZMENY Z JOIN
     ZMENY_DILY ZD
     ON ZD.ID_ZMENY = Z.ID
WHERE  1=1 -- %sql ???
ORDER BY Z.ID DESC;
```

Alternatively, you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT z.*
FROM ZMENY Z
WHERE Z.ID IN (SELECT ID_ZMENY FROM ZMENY_DILY ZD)
ORDER BY Z.ID DESC;
```

Comment: Using DISTINCT threw this: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB .... IN clause returned the same